# Why isn't "bulkDelete()" working in my bot command?

Tags: lua, discord, bots, luvit

I'm trying to code a Discord bot in lua at the moment and I've having some difficulties. I'm trying to create a bulk delete command for my bot, but it seems to not work and only returns "400 - Bad Request" upon typing the command. Am I doing something wrong? I've tried doing `message.channel:bulkDelete(3)` and it still doesn't work. (I am pretty new to coding Discord bots in lua.)

Code:

```
local discordia = require('discordia')
local client = discordia.Client()

local prefix = "+"
local adminid = 645671868728082432

client:on("ready", function() -- bot is ready
    print("Logged in")
end)

client:on("messageCreate", function(message)
    local content = message.content
    local member = message.member
    local author = message.author
    local memberid = member.id
    local args = content:split(" ")

    if args[1] == prefix.. "delete" then
        if not member:hasRole(adminid) then
            message:reply("<@" ..author.id.. ">**, you do not have permission to use this command.**")
            return
        end
        message.guild:getChannel(message.channel.id):bulkDelete(3)
    end
end)
```

Comment: assuming you have your bot token.  if you do their simple PingPong example, it does OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this method requires a table of MessageID-resolvable objects like Message object itself or its ID as string.

Read documentation here: https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki/GuildTextChannel#bulkdeletemessages

Comment: No it doesn't.  You can just put in a number  --  https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete

Comment: the OP has `local discordia = require('discordia')` in the code. the link in this answer would indicate how `bulkDelete` is implemented in `discordia` which can differ from the `discord.js` implementation.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Yes it does. You can't just put in a number -- https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/blob/master/libs/containers/GuildTextChannel.lua#L71

Comment: OK well, I didn't see that guild part.  I had looked at https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/blob/master/libs/client/API.lua#L314 before posting that comment, and it didn't specify any distinction.